# Should I either hide from the url or store in a session in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails site I am working on that has users and locations

a user has many locations and a location can have many users so i have a many to many ...

```
has_many :through
```

my question is this...most users will only have one location and only one location so when they log in should i have it in the url or store in a session

```
/some_location/users
```

or should i store the location in a session with a method like this

```
def current_location
  @location ||= Location.find(session[:location_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  @location = current_user.locations.first
  session[:location] = @location.id
  @location
end
```

and have the url cleaner

```
/users
```

If i did do it the above way with the name of the location in the path how would i do the routes

Answer (score 0):

If the users don't need direct access to the location (or if you have an easy way for them to switch locations) you probably want to use a session. This will make navigation simpler and less confusing for the most of your users with only one location while allowing you to handle the edge case of a user with multiple locations in a less complicated fashion.

Answer (score 0):

For users with more than one location, the code below will return random location

```
@location = current_user.locations.first
```

You can prioritize selection of the location - say alphabetical

```
@location = current_user.locations.order("name DESC").first
```

But, when the user changes location, his URL will get mapped under a different location. It may or may not be what you want.